# What's a workable way setup an Akka cluster in a multi-node Docker environment?

Tags: scala, akka, docker

Assume the picture below.  Each Docker container belongs to a single Akka cluster "foo", and each
container has runs one cluster node.  The IP address assigned by Docker (inside the container) is 
given in green.  All the internal ports are 9090 but are mapped to various external ports on the host.

[image]

What is the Akka URI for the node in say Docker 5?  Would it be akka.tcp://foo@10.0.0.195:9101

I've read some blogs on Akka and Docker that involve linking but this doesn't seem workable (?) for
a multi-node deployment and I'm not sure how linking scales to 100s of nodes.

I need some way for Akka to know the address of its cluster.  Left to its own devices, Docker 5 might
decide it's reachable at akka.tcp://foo@192.178.1.2:9090, which is useless/unreachable outside of its own container.

At this point I'm thinking I pass the host's IP and port (e.g. 10.0.0.195:9101) to the Docker container
as a parameter on start-up for Akka to use when it configures itself.

Would this work, or is there a better way to go?

Comment: In the latest Akka 2.3.8 there is no way to set a bind address (which in your docker 5 case would be 192.168.1.2:9090) different from the public address (in your case would be 10.0.0.195).

However [this feature](https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/15007) is already in the current Akka master and will be released in 2015 Q1.

In the meantime there are [couple of solutions](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/akka-user/docker/akka-user/B0pz0ns7UbA/YmZazgiM5KoJ) that allow you to do this even on the current Akka version. Try searching akka-user mailing list for docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed!  New Akka (snapshot at time of posting) does have nifty new binds that solve this problem.  Example of use here: https://github.com/gzoller/docker-exp/tree/cluster